# SML : Changing value of INT in a structure

Tags: algorithm, types, sml, smlnj

I've got a small problem.

I made calculations and all my ids are not following each other anymore (because of some delete during the calculus). Unfortunately, to make my result valid, I need this order... :/

So in order to simply the task, I made an external function, that will "rename" all the IDs but I do not know how to perform this.

Here is the function that I've got :

```
fun setId (W {id, ...}) = 
let 
in
    print( "[" ^ Int.toString (id) ^ "]");
    print( "[" ^ Int.toString (!nextId) ^ "]\n");
    Ref.incr nextId
end
```

(for the one who are wandering `app`is just a homemade function to perform the same calcul on each element of a list, but it's not important.)

When I'm execute this code, I obtain in output :

```
[0][0]
[1][1]
[2][2]
[3][3]
[4][4]
[5][5]
[6][6]
[7][7]
[8][8]
[9][9]
[10][10]
[11][11]
[12][12]
[13][13]
[14][14]
[15][15]
[16][16]
[17][17]
[18][18]
[19][19]
[20][20]
[21][21]
[22][22]
[39][23]
[40][24]
[41][25]
[42][26]
[43][27]
[44][28]
[45][29]
[46][30]
[47][31]
[48][32]
[49][33]
[50][34]
[51][35]
[52][36]
[53][37]
```

as you can see there is a big problem `[23] [39]` the list does not have following numbers. :/

Basically, I would like the function `setId`to be able to modify the ID of the Node. But I don't know how :/

Here is the datatype `Node` for understanding purposes :

```
    datatype node =
          W of {
              id              : int
            , predId          : int option
            , creationDepcy   : Dependency.depcy
            , nominalDepcies  : Dependency.depcy list ref
            , pattern         : Termstore.store
            , propositions    : Propstore.pstore
            , nominals        : Propstore.pstore
            , diamonds        : Termstore.store
            , boxes           : Termstore.store
            , disjunctions    : Termstore.store
            , nglstore        : Termstore.store
            , lazyProps       : Lazystore.store
            , lazyNoms        : Lazynomstore.store
            , lazyBoxes       : Lazyboxstore.store
            , blockedDiamonds : (Term.index * int) list ref
            , branchPoints    : int list ref
            }
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `id` is typed `int` it cannot be modified. If you change it to `int ref` then you can modify it, but you will also have to change the accessors to dereference the `ref`.

An alternative solution is to create an array that maps from old IDs to new IDs and use this array for presentation, but that seems even more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Since `ints` are immutable -- you could take your list of nodes and replace it with a new list of nodes:

```
fun newID (W(x), i) =
           W({
              id               = i
            , predId           =  #predId x
            , creationDepcy    =  #creationDepcy x
            , nominalDepcies   =  #nominalDepcies x
            , pattern          =  #pattern x
            , propositions     =  #propositions x
            , nominals         =  #nominals x
            , diamonds         =  #diamonds x
            , boxes            =  #boxes x
            , disjunctions     =  #disjunctions x
            , nglstore         =  #nglstore x
            , lazyProps        =  #lazyProps x
            , lazyNoms         =  #lazyNoms x
            , lazyBoxes        =  #lazyBoxes x
            , blockedDiamonds  =  #blockedDiamonds x
            , branchPoints     =  #branchPoints x
           });


fun imap _ [] _ = []
|   imap f (x::xs) i = f(x,i):: (imap f xs (i+1));
```

(`imap` stands for "increment map")

Then if `xs` is a list of nodes the function call

```
imap newID xs 0
```

will yield a new list of nodes with the `id` fields consecutive ints starting with `0`

Disclaimer: I didn't try this on your setup of course, by I created a datatype of records which had an `id` field and successfully used this approach. Obviously this isn't something you would want to do a lot of because of all the copying, but if it is at one specific point in your code it should be okay.

Comment: Yes, with the caveat that it is a *new* list of nodes, and anything holding a reference to the initial list will not see the changes.

Comment: @DougCurrie Yes, that is an important caveat. I think that it would make the most sense for OP to either follow your suggestion of changing `id` to an `int ref` or finding a way to rewrite it so as to use immutable data structures throughout.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly equivalent to John's solution, here is how one would update a list of nodes without using references, using a fold instead. The function `setId` is the same.

```
fun setIds firstId ws =
    #1 (foldr (fn (w,(ws',nextId)) => (setId w nextId::ws', nextId+1)) ([],firstId) ws)
```

Running `setIds 1 [w1, w2, w3, ...]` would yield `[w1', w2', w3', ...]`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize how close my answer is to John's. I'll just shorten it to highlight the difference.